# What happens, exactly, if you set the session name after the execution of session_start() in PHP < 7.2?

Tags: php, session

Starting from PHP 7.2, if you set a new session name via `session_name()` after having started the session (`sesssion_start()`), a warning is triggered.

Before V 7.2, you didn't get any warning, and the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) says:

> session_name() checks session status, previously it only checked
> cookie status. Therefore, older session_name() allows to call
> session_name() after session_start() which may crash PHP and may
> result in misbehaviors.

I am trying to understand the consequences of setting the session name after having started the session in a PHP < 7.2 environment (in particular, in a situation where `session.auto_start = 1`, which I can't control) and I am not sure what they mean with "misbehaviors" here. I think that what can happen is only that the session (the session cookie, if it's a cookie-based session) gets the default name instead of the name you defined: this, in some situations, might have security implications, but sessions will work anyway.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Well if it explicitly says, _“which may crash PHP”_, then I suppose they did not just sprinkle that in there based on nothing.

Comment: They say "may crash PHP ... and may result in misbehaviors." . The first part is clear, the second is very vague and I am trying to understand the actual consequences. If PHP crashes, it's bad but still more desirable than a situation where only apparently everything is working fine.

Comment: I’m guessing that depends, at least partially, on the specific application logic in each case. But with `session.auto_start = 1`, the whole discussion seems a bit pointless - using `session_name()` in a setting capacity can hardly _ever_ make sense in that scenario?

Comment: IF something happens, for sure it depends on the application logic but again, it's very vague :) I would like to understand what actually happens.